# Pass JavaScript variables from a server Node.js to another web [NOT embedded JavaScript code]

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, get

First of all I explain the problem I have and then we see if the solution I have chosen is viable.

I have a traditional web page (HTML, CSS, **JavaScript**) hosted on a free hosting where I don't have SSH access, nor Root privileges, let's call it **web A**.

On this website I have a music player (online radio) where songs names, authors names and lyrics are shown.

On **server B**, I have an API that runs with **NodeJS** and gets a `string` that I store in a `variable` with the song lyrics being played on the online radio.

The idea that occurred to me was to pass the Lyrics variable from server B to web A.

As in web A I have a javaScript script that feeds the HTML of that page with content, I need the **JavaScript code** to incorporate in **Server B** to **send** the variable and the **JavaScript code** for **web A** to **receive** it,

I need a simple JavaScript code, **not embedded** Javascript code inside HTML page.

Comment: I recommend you look into Heroku to keep web A and server B on the same system. It's free to a certain extent, and maybe you can expand your plan once your website has grown. I think the problem with keeping these two separate is that your data could be queried by other people who aren't supposed to get ahold of your lyrics.

Answer (score 1):

You can call your server from your web page with ajax or setup a websocket channel if you want that your server push data.

Comment: Exactly. Maybe you can just query your Node server for the lyrics?